# How to stream video in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, video, video-streaming

I am trying to stream the video in the blade file. Normally video is loading but I am not able to go to and fro.

Here is the link which I followed: 
https://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial

I have added the class things in my `App/VideoStream.php` class and in the blade

```
<?php
$video_path = 'my_video_ath';

$tmp = new \App\VideoStream($video_path);
$tmp->start();

?>


<video controls preload="auto" src="{{ $tmp }}" width="100%"></video>'
```

Whats issue in this, please help me out.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors on screen or in the log file? What exactly is not working?

Comment: 504 Gateway Time-out @Mike

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The class you're using is to handle the actual range requests. you need to provide a route that uses that as well:

```
Route::get('stream', function () {
   $video_path = 'my_video_path';

   $tmp = new \App\VideoStream($video_path);
   $tmp->start();
})->name('stream');
```

Then the HTML will be:

```
<video controls preload="auto" src="{{ route('stream') }}" width="100%"></video>'
```

[The class in question can be found in Github](https://gist.github.com/ranacseruet/9826293#file-videostream-php)

Comment: Now just video player with loader is loading. I had changes in a route like :

`Route::get('/player', function () {
    return view('video_test');
});

Route::get('stream', function () {
    $video_path = 'mypath';
      
    $tmp = new \App\VideoStream($video_path);
    $tmp->start();
 })->name('stream');`

Blade: 

`<video controls preload="auto" src="{{ route('stream') }}" width="100%"></video>'
`

Comment: Please be careful that we should include path only not whole link, else it will not work.

Comment: Is there a way to do this same process but with AJAX?