# How to stream a video stored in laravel with react?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios

I have a video file stored in the backend (laravel) and I want to display this video in my front end (react)
how to stream that video using axios?

my laravel code:

```
Route::get('/video', function () {
    $response =  response()->file(public_path('/Articles/Videos/del659d4345-980b-4e4a-a499-84618da19107.mp4'));
    return $response;
    
});
```

react

```
http
    .get('/api/video')
    .then((data) => {
      setdata(data.data);
    })
```

it works perfectly in the backend with laravel, I can rewind the video and it sends keep-alive axios requests.
I tried to just send the url of the video to the front it works but I can't rewind the video.
now how could I use axios and react to display that video?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58709069/how-to-stream-video-in-laravel might help.

Comment: @apokryfos thank you for helping but I already don't have problem with streaming video in laravel I mentioned that before in my post. my problem is how to make my front end display video ... the video is working prefectly in the backend but how to send axios request to make it works in react

Comment: Streaming a video and allowing rewinding and seeking requires [range request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range) support for your backend endpoint which you currently do not have meaning that you have to send the entire video to the front-end before you are able to start playback which is not generally an ideal situation. The linked question shows a tutorial that implements a class to support range requests

Comment: @apokryfos You mentioned something I hadn't thought of. according to my code I was returning the whole file by response it is not a good idea specially with big size files... I followed the link you sent and changed my php code... the problem now I got CORS error as a response for my axios request

Comment: Assuming the request URL is the same, try the same request in postman, sometimes the CORS error indicates that there was an error page shown that did not have the CORS headers included.