# Does Laravel's Storage class automatically stream files?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I have an online course platform, and I'm thinking about the best way to make my classes available for my students to watch.

For that, I decided to use laravel that is hosted on an Amazon S2 instance, and my videos (.mp4 format) are being saved on amazon S3.

In my view, I'm using the following code to return the desired video:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="{{ env('APP_URL') }}loadVideo" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

And in my `'loadVideo'` route I'm running the following function:

```
public function loadVideo(){
    $video = self::getFile('classes/how-to-make-a-cake.mp4');
    return $video;
}

public static function getFile($document){
    return Storage::disk('s3')->get($document);
}
```

Cool, with that I can already see the video running in the browser, just click play to watch it.

In this regard, I have three questions:

1. In Network (Chrome Tab), when the video is
   playing, I can see my route ('loadVideo') loading automatically, can this be
   considered a video stream?
2. Is this the most correct way to stream
   videos into my platform?
3. Why, as a user, I can't change the time
   of the video?

Comment: I think the way you've done it the entire video goes to the client in one request, which is sub-optimal. Laravel does not implement streaming which allows seeking out of the box.  If you want to go down the rabbit hole here's a couple of links for you: (a) [how to stream a video in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58709069/how-to-stream-video-in-laravel) and (b) [HTTP range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range)

Comment: 'Amazon S2 instance' - EC2 instance or S3 bucket?

Comment: Also, this is an unfocused question. @apokryfos's links are great; in terms of AWS, you're looking for HTTP range requests to S3 using the PHP SDK.